# Triangle shape in java

Tags: java, shapes

This is my program for hollow triangle but I actually want to print another triangle in it as I showed below. I have tried making for loops but all in vain

```
     ` *
      ***
     ** **
    **   **
   **     **
  **        **
 **************
***************`

 int z=1;

  for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
  {
    for (int j=7; j>i; j--)
    {
      System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("*");

    if (i!=0)
    {
      for (int k=1; k<=z; k++)
      {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.print("*");
      z+=2;
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
  }

  for (int i=0; i<=z+1; i++)
  {
   System.out.print("*");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice puzzle for me today, here is your code

```
int size = 12;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
    for (int j = size; j > i - 3; j--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    for (int j = size; j >= i; j--) {
    System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("**");
    for (int j = 0; j <= i * 2; j++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("**");
}
System.out.println("");

for (int i = 0; i < (size * 2) + 6; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
    System.out.print(" ");
    } else {
    System.out.print("*");
    }
}
System.out.println("");
for (int i = 0; i < (size * 2) + 8; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
    System.out.print("");
    } else {
    System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```